# Our app crashes only when downloaded from Google Play. Why?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, crash

I have a crash during the (unity) app launch that only appear when the app is downloaded from the Play Store. I ran plenty of tests and I observed this crash even with an empty Unity project.

I have Google Play Games, Firebase & Admob running on the app, but I tried to remove all plugins from the project, and as I said, I tried uploading an empty unity project and it also crashes.
The same app installed directly from the apk file works fine.

The crash disappears if I clear the app's storage just after install.

The crash happens on Android 9 but not on Android 5.1.
The crash does not happen if I load the same app using a different project on the google play console (tried with the empty app that crashes with the first playStore project & same build parameters).

This crash appears only if I compile with il2CPP... Unfortunately I need it to have the 64 bits version.

Edit: As I need a 64 bits version my basic build is done with arm64v8 & armV7 architectures, sent to PlayStore with an Android App Bundle, but I tried with an apk & armV7 only, same crash...

All this is tested with closed alpha in PlayStore project

Here is the log:

```
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000073a1529a10
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH: Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH: Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/whyred/whyred:9/PKQ1.180904.001/V10.3.1.0.PEIMIXM:user/release-keys'
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH: Revision: '0'
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH: pid: 15157, tid: 15203, name: UnityMain  >>> com.company.app <<<
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x0   0000007170796768  x1   000000716eee2d38  x2   0000007170800000  x3   0000007170796400
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x4   00000071709b7000  x5   0000007170796480  x6   000000716eee2de8  x7   000000716eee2d58
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x8   00000000464c457f  x9   000000716ef06e18  x10  00000000001aaaf8  x11  0000000000001fff
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x12  000000000000001d  x13  000000716eb0a2b0  x14  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab  x15  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x16  000000720eae31d8  x17  000000720e9f1f70  x18  0000000000000000  x19  00000071729a1da0
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x20  000000716db8fd84  x21  000000716f0ab000  x22  000000716eeda918  x23  000000716f0ab000
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x24  000000716f0ab000  x25  000000716f0ab000  x26  00000000000000f3  x27  000000716db8fd80
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     x28  000000000000045f  x29  00000071729a1e20  x30  000000716e021fec
2019-06-20 23:13:32.840 15157-15203/? E/CRASH:     sp   00000071729a1d90  pc   000000716e021fd8  pstate 0000000000000000
```

Comment: Some missing `arm64-v8a` native libs?
Be sure that all the native libraries you use have binaries for this architecture. Or try using `abiFilters` in `build.gradle` excluding this architecture to see if it's a problem with this one only.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried with a single armV7 build (same architecture that works with Mono), got the same crash...

Answer (score 3):

I have been experiencing similar issues, crashes on startup on android 9.0 but only when the app was downloaded from google play store. The crash in my case was caused by a unity bug that backed up old IL2CPP files on new versions. I fixed this issue by adding the following lines to my android manifest file inside the `<Application>` tag.

`android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" 
tools:replace="android:allowBackup`

The bug reported, more info and the fix I mentioned above can be seen [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-il2cpp-app-crashes-on-2019-dot-1-0a12-and-up-on-launch-if-old-il2cpp-files-from-2019-dot-1-0a11-and-below-are-backuped)

All credit to SJWEESALS from unity forums for this one helped me out a lot.

Comment: Oops, I found the same answer but I totally forgot that I posted the question here.
Thanks a lot, I hope this will be useful for other devs, it tooks me a lot of time to find this post & answer on the unity forum.

Comment: Solved a similar issue for a native Android app for me, thanks! Surprisingly, it only occured on one device...